# An error occurred while installing logstash-core-event-java (5.1.2)

Tags: proxy, logstash, logstash-configuration

I'm installing Logstash on a Windows Server 2012 over a proxy. I've set the HTTP and HTTPS proxies. I've tried both:

```
set HTTP_PROXY "<myhost:port>"
set HTTPS_PROXY "<myhost:port>"
```

And:

```
C:\ELK_Stack\logstash\bin>set JRUBY_OPTS="-J-Dhttp.proxyHost=<myhost> -J-Dhttp.proxyPort=<myport>"
```

And I'm installing logstash-input-beats as a plugin:

```
C:\ELK_Stack\logstash\bin>logstash-plugin install logstash-input-beats
```

However I receive the following error:

```
C:\ELK_Stack\logstash\bin>logstash-plugin install logstash-input-beats
Validating logstash-input-beats
Installing logstash-input-beats
Error Bundler::InstallError, retrying 1/10
An error occurred while installing logstash-core-event-java (5.1.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install logstash-core-event-java -v '5.1.2'` succeeds before bundling.
Error Bundler::InstallError, retrying 2/10
An error occurred while installing logstash-core-event-java (5.1.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install logstash-core-event-java -v '5.1.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: This [response](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/5581/#issuecomment-260701269) could be helpful, since the issue seems to be ideal!

Comment: I've tried to add the proxy configuration to the ruby-maven-libs settings file, `/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/ruby-maven-libs-3.3.9/maven-home/conf/settings.xml` but I get the same error.